# how to split a list of dictionary base on a certain value

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list l1

```
l1 = [
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "1", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 100},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "2", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 200},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "3", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 300},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "4", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 400},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "1", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 102},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "2", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 302},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "3", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 567},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "4", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 850},
...]
```

How can I make a pythonic solution to convert the l1 to become below?

```
l1 = [
[{"kubernetes_pod_name": "1", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 100},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "2", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 200},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "3", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 300},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "4", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 400}],
[{"kubernetes_pod_name": "1", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 102},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "2", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 302},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "3", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 567},
{"kubernetes_pod_name": "4", "resolution_ms": 10, "value": 850}]
...]
```

I'm trying to make it into a nested list based on their appearing structure and will need to use this data for future display.

The criteria of the splitting is based on the value of the kubernetes_pod_name, but not only yhe value it self, but the section of it, here, Kubernetes_node_name 1,2,3,4 appeared and then starting duplicate after, hence splitting for the upcoming duplication.

Thanks

Comment: What would be the value to split in your case?

Comment: What criteria would you use to split them?  What does "appearing structure" mean?

Comment: `out = [[d for d in l1 if d['value'] % 100 == 0], [d for d in l1 if d['value'] % 100 != 0]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the simple logic is to count the unique values of  `'kubernetes_pod_name'` and make group accordingly

**Note**: Expecting that all pod name will be present in row

Code:

```
uni = len(set([l['kubernetes_pod_name'] for l in l1]))
[l1[i:i+uni] for i in range(0, len(l1), uni)]
```

Output:

```
[[{'kubernetes_pod_name': '1', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 100},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '2', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 200},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '3', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 300},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '4', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 400}],
 [{'kubernetes_pod_name': '1', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 102},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '2', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 302},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '3', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 567},
  {'kubernetes_pod_name': '4', 'resolution_ms': 10, 'value': 850}]]
```

Using recursion:

```
def recur(lst, ls, new):
    if len(ls)<=1:
        return new + [lst[ls[0]:]]
    else:
        new = new + [lst[ls[0]:ls[1]]]
    return recur(lst, ls[1:],new)

recur(l1, list(range(0, len(l1), uni)), [])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking to do use recursion or something. but this approach certainly can work.

Comment: @JamesXu try updated code.